# Показать все метки на Яндекс карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Для загрузки объектов на карту использую следующий скрипт

```
function LoadObjects(myMap) {
   myMap.geoObjects.remove(loadingObjectManager);
    loadingObjectManager = new ymaps.LoadingObjectManager(url + '?bbox=%b',
    {
        clusterize: true,
        clusterHasBalloon: true,
        geoObjectOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
        clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: true
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(loadingObjectManager);
};
```

Скрипт создания карты

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [@centerYandexMap],
        zoom: 12,
        controls: ['fullscreenControl', 'geolocationControl', 'typeSelector', 'zoomControl']
    }, {
        avoidFractionalZoom: false
    });
    if (параметр == 'True') {
        LoadObjects(myMap);
        myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
    }
    $(window).resize(function () {
        myMap.container.fitToViewport();
    });
});
```

Метки на карте показываются, но видимая область карты не включает необходимые точки. Как я понимаю проблема в `myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds())`, т.к. `myMap.geoObjects.getBounds()` возвращает `null`, и само выражение `myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds())` возвращается с ошибкой (под отладчиком так и не удалось добраться до того момента где происходит ошибка, но скрипт следующий за этим выражением не отрабатывает).

Пробовал следующим образом, но в консоль ничего не выводится

```
var qwe = ymaps.geoQuery(myMap.geoObjects).then(function(){
console.log(qwe);
});
```

Comment: loadingObjectManager сделан для того чтобы оптимизировать загрузку данных с сервера, поэтому он загружает не все геообъекты, а только те которые попадают в видимую область. Соответственно если вы выставите необходимый вам Bounds то loadingObjectManager сделает запросы за всеми геообъектами которые в этот баундс попадают.

Comment: @se0ga можно подробнее на примере, как понять выставить Bounds

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что вы можете выставить любой bounds так myMap.setBounds([[59.999302212190216, 30.22371063232047],[59.880094970125405, 30.44206390380444]]); и в последствии loadingObjectManager загрузит для него данные

Comment: А сейчас на основании чего формируется область? на основании ответа метода?

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Область по которой запрашиваются данные с сервера формируется на основании центра и зума выставленного вами тут center: [@centerYandexMap], zoom: 12.

Comment: Т.е. на основании массива полученных объектов нельзя вписать их в какую то область?

Comment: Вы можете получить bounds добавленных объектов на карту так https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/LoadingObjectManager-docpage/#getBounds , но я все равно не понимаю, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Если вы получите bounds и потом измените bounds карты, то LoadingObjectManager отправит на сервер новый запрос с новым bounds в котором могут придти новые метки. Правильней выставить bounds, который вам нужен, а LoadingObjectManager сделает запрос с ним, получит данные и отобразит их на карте.